# MATLAB surface plot inputs

Tags: matlab, plot

I wrote code that plots 2 subplots, a 3D surface plot and a 2D contour plot. However, the variables/vectors used in the plots change and I need to re-plot them. Here is what I have so far. I keep getting and error and MATLAB crashes every time I run the code.

Plot that works:

```
subplot(2,1,1);
plotHandle =     surf(xMeters(xStart:xEnd),yMeters(yStart:yEnd),ELEV(yStart:yEnd,xStart:xEnd));
subplot(2,1,2);
contour(xMeters,yMeters,ELEV);
hold on;
plotHandle2 = plot(xTop,yTop,'b');
plotHandle3 = plot(xBottom,yBottom,'b');
plotHandle4 = plot(xLeft,yLeft,'b');
plotHandle5 = plot(xRight,yRight,'b');
hold off;
```

Then I try to re-plot it after doing some operations on the variables/vectors and
this is where it breaks down:

```
subplot(2,1,1);
set(plotHandle,'XData',xMeters(xStart:xEnd));
set(plotHandle,'YData',yMeters(yStart:yEnd));
set(plotHandle,'ZData',ELEV(yStart:yEnd,xStart:xEnd));
subplot(2,1,2);
set(plotHandle2,'XData',xTop);
set(plotHandle2,'YData',yTop);
set(plotHandle3,'XData',xBottom);
set(plotHandle3,'YData',yBottom);
set(plotHandle4,'XData',xLeft);
set(plotHandle4,'YData',yLeft);
set(plotHandle5,'XData',xRight);
set(plotHandle5,'YData',yRight);

drawnow;
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: The error says memory is full. And there was a problem using set. And I got this warning: "Warning: line XData length (90802) and YData length (1) must be equal"

Comment: The issue is my code, not MATLAB. My code isn't running properly and runs for a long time if I don't force quit.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab crashing, when you are not using mex or other external interfaces, would be a case for contacting Mathworks customer support.

Comment: I'm not with Mathworks. Anyway, if you want to increase chances of anyone being able to help you, you should provide a minimal but complete example demonstrating the behaviour. The code in your question lacks the data. You might want to combine data generation, initial plotting, data modification, replotting, all in one self-contained m-file.